# what is different between validation set and query set?

Tags: validation, testing

i While reading machine learning articles , I came across the following terms:

1. train set
2. test set
3. validation set
4. query set
5. support set
6. sample set

I am really confused .

is validation set and query set the same?

Answer (score 0):

The training data is composed of train and test examples, alternately referred to as the support and query set.

Validation sets are used for parameter tuning.

Further read: https://meta-learning.fastforwardlabs.com/